# Full explanation on the cancellation property: $\;\sin{\big(\arcsin(x)\big)}=x,\; \forall\; x\in [-1,1]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Please, I need full explanation on the cancellation property applied to the composition of functions below
 $$\;\arcsin{\big(\sin(x)\big)}=x,\; \forall\; x\in \Big[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\Big] ,\;\;\;\sin{\big(\arcsin(x)\big)}=x,\; \forall\; x\in [-1,1].$$
and why is $$\sin{\big(\arcsin(x)\big)}\neq x,\; \forall\; x\in \Bbb{R}?$$

I need some explanation on the kind of maps, how the values are calculated and perhaps, some drawings for clarity!

Comment: As for your last question, you can't take the arcsine of any number not within the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: $sin(x) \in [-1,1]$

Comment: I discourage the use of the notation $\sin^{-1}$ as that can cause confusion and frustration across borders as it is ambiguous whether the `^-1` is intended to mean multiplicative inversion or functional inversion.  The notation $\arcsin$ is superior.

Comment: You'we mixed them up. Replace $[-1,1]$ and $\Big[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\Big]$

Comment: @JMoravitz: Noted, thanks!

Comment: @Zeekless: Thanks!

Comment: The second inequality holds if $|x| > 1 $ not for all $x$

Comment: As for how the cancellation property works... just remember how $\arcsin(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ act.  $\arcsin(x)$ returns the unique angle within the range $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ such that the sine of that angle gives $x$.  Note that $-1\leq \sin(x)\leq 1$ for all real $x$, so (*the real*) $\arcsin(x)$ is undefined for $x$ outside of $[-1,1]$ (*things get weirder when allowing complex inputs and outputs*) and note that there are multiple inputs which map to the same output for $\sin$ such as how $\sin(0)=\sin(2\pi)$, so $\arcsin$ can't distinguish between them.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'll just say it's a pet peeve of mine how widespread the notational abuse of $\sin^2(x)$ taken to mean $(\sin(x))^2$ is. This basically only happens with trigonometric functions and for no good reason honestly.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I've encountered it with $\ln^2(n)$ within the past month as well that they intended $\ln^2(n)$ to mean $(\ln(n))^2$ rather than $\ln(\ln(n))$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh no. It's spreading...

Comment: The function $g(x)=arcsin(sin(x))$ is defined and continuous for all reals and the graph is interesting if you have never seen it (use a calculator or compute the derivative ... carefully ...  and use that to sketch the graph by hand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about Domain and Range.

$$ {\rm sin}(x) \;: \;\mathbb{R} \rightarrow  [-1, 1]$$

$$ {\rm arcsin}(x) \;: \;[-1, 1] \rightarrow  \Big[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\Big]$$

$$
\Downarrow
$$

$$ {\rm sin(arcsin(}(x)) \;: \;[-1, 1] \xrightarrow[id]{}  [-1, 1]$$

$$ {\rm arcsin(sin(}(x)) \;: \;\mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \Big[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\Big]$$

The last map is not an identity, but its restriction on $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is:

$$ {\rm arcsin(sin(}(x))_{[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]} \;: \;\Big[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\Big] \xrightarrow[id]{}  \Big[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\Big].$$

Answer (score 1):

This is all fairly simple.

By convention $\arcsin x$ is a function that takes value between -1 and 1 (inclusive) and returns angle between $-\pi/2$ and $+\pi/2$. That's it. $\arcsin$ will **never** return an angle outside of this segment.

But you can calculate sine function for any angle, outside of $[-\pi/2,+\pi/2]$ range. For such angles inverse sine function will never return the original angle.

For example:

$$\arcsin(\sin\frac{\pi}{6})=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

$$\arcsin(\sin\frac{5\pi}{6})=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

In other words, identity:

$$\arcsin(\sin x)=x$$

...is valid only for $x\in [-\pi/2, +\pi/2]$

Answer (score 1):

For example $$\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4})={\sqrt2\over 2}$$but so does $\sin(\dfrac{3\pi}{4})$ , $\sin(\dfrac{9\pi}{4})$ , $\sin(\dfrac{11\pi}{4})$ , ... so what is the value of $\arcsin(x)$? There to avoid ambiguity, $\arcsin$ function has bee defines such that for each argument gives a result in $[-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}]$ since $\sin$ function is bijective at this interval.$$\arcsin(x)=\{\theta\in[-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}]\quad,\quad\sin\theta=x\}$$

Answer (score 1):

What is the answer to this question: *for what $x$ the equation* $\sin(x)=0$?

You can clearly see that you could say $x=0$ or $x=\pi$ as well $x=2\pi,3\pi,4\pi\dots$ and so on. All this answers are clearly different from each other, so if I don't restrict myself on a certain domain the question $$\arcsin(\sin(x))=x$$ has more than one answer. For example let us choose $x={\pi\over4}$ and $y={3\pi\over4}$ and compute $$\arcsin(\sin(y))=\arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}) = {\pi\over4} = x$$
but clearly $x\neq y$. So in general this equalities hold only on a smaller domain: if you want to invert the function $\sin(x)$ you have to do it in $[-{\pi\over 2},{\pi\over 2}]$ and in this case: $$\arcsin(x): [-1,1]\rightarrow [-{\pi\over 2},{\pi\over 2}]$$ and as well $$\sin(x):[-{\pi\over 2},{\pi\over 2}]\rightarrow[-1,1]$$ in this cases every element in the domain gets mapped to one element of the codomain, so the answer to that equations is unique